# How to group a family of related types in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

So in my app, I have a grid component that's used for a few different types of data.

All types of data are fetched through different API endpoints, using different filtering options, etc. All of this is properly defined with appropriate types, and work well enough when I'm working with a specific type.

How can I "group" all of these types together by "family"?

I'd like to be able to describe the "shape" of a family (e.g it has a Filter type, a Response type, etc.), and be able to enforce the relationship (e.g when we have this data type, we need this filter type).

I've tried various approaches using interfaces and classes, but I can't specify a type with a "." in it; that's reserved to namespaces.

Namespaces are promising, but I can't enforce the "shape" of them, so I can't have my component using a common "abstract" namespace.

Any thought on the approach I should use?

EDIT: For clarification, here's what I'd like to do:

```js
type View<D, F> = {
  // these should be the actual types, not an instance of
  Data: D;
  Filter: F;
}
type TasksView = View<Task, TaskFilter>;
type ProjectsView = View<Project, ProjectFilter>;

interface GridProps<T extends View> {
  filters: T.Filter;
}
function Grid<T>(props: GridProps<T>) {
  const getData(props.filters): T.Data {
    // return data
  }
  return (
    <table>
    </table>
  )
}

function MyTasksGrid = Grid<TasksView>
function MyProjectsGrid = Grid<ProjectsView>
```

Not 100% syntactically correct, but I hope it illustrates the concept. Basically I want to "link" the `Task` and `TaskFilter` types via a common structure.

However, `T.Data` as described above doesn't work as T is not a namespace (`'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here`).

Comment: Sounds like you should be using interfaces but it's hard to say from this description

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say by this `function MyTasksGrid = Grid<TasksView>`

Answer (score 1):

When you have to create a "common" interface for objects that has some common fields while others are different you can use the `|` notation and define a new `type`. Check the example below:

```
//Two similar objects with partially common interfaces
interface Bird {
  name: string
  age: number
  type: 'BIRD'
  //Different
  feathers_color: string
  fly: ()=>void
}
 
interface Fish {
  name: string
  age: number
  type: 'FISH'
  //Different
  fins: number
  swim: ()=>void
}

type Animal = Fish | Bird;

let my_animal: Animal = {
  name: 'Karl'
  age: 8
  type: 'FISH' as 'FISH'
  fins: 3
  swim: () => { console.log("I'm swimming...") }
}

//Properties that are accessible without verifying if the animal is a bird or a fish
console.log(my_animal.name);
console.log(my_animal.age);
console.log(my_animal.type);
if(my_animal.type === 'FISH'){
  //Properties that are accessible only after checking the type
  console.log(my_animal.fins);
  my_animal.swim(); //Typescript will not complain here
}
```

Notice: when you create an object you must specify the `type` parameter manually.

Notice 2: this approach doesn't usually work well (in terms of maintainability) when you need multiple grades of grouping. You will have to define multiple `type` fields for each group and it can become messy really fast.

**UPDATE**
This should be the implementation of what you asked using the method outlined above

```
interface Task{}
interface TaskFilter{}
interface Project{}
interface ProjectFilter{}

interface TaskView {
  Data: Task
  Filter: TaskFilter
}

interface ProjectView{
  Data: Project
  Filter: ProjectFilter
}

type View = TaskView | ProjectView

interface GridProps<T extends View> {
  filters: T['Filter'];
}

//Alternative 1: Without grid props, that wrapper seemed excessive for the definition of the type
function Grid<T extends View>(props: T) {
  function getData(filter: T['Filter']): T['Data'] {
    // return data
    return {}
  }
  return (
    <table>
    </table>
  )
}

//Alternative 2: maybe I'm missing something, so I add also a version with Grid Props
function Grid<T extends View, G extends GridProps<T>>(props: G) {
  function getData(filter: G['filters']): T['Data'] {
    // return data
    return {}
  }
  return (
    <table>
    </table>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's kinda what I'm doing right now, but not all sub-types have all the same properties, and it is indeed very messy. I often have to cast from one type to the other, and type errors slip by unnoticed because of that.

Comment: @emilecantin If this is the answer you were looking for please validate it. Otherwise, tell us what is missing so we can improve our answers.

Comment: I clarified my question with some code above.

Comment: @emilecantin I have added an implementation of what you asked me. Tell me if it meets your requirements

Comment: `T['Filter']` <-- This seems promising; I'll try it out. Thanks!